# what is WIZARD_ID?

Tags: visual-studio, wizard, visual-c++

win32console.vsz

```
VSWIZARD 7.0
Wizard=VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.10.0
Param="WIZARD_NAME = Application"
Param="RELATIVE_PATH = VCWizards\AppWiz\Generic"
Param="WIZARD_ID = 75"
```

what is WIZARD_ID? any official document or specification?

Comment: An internal ID for the Visual Studio "Win32 Console Application" project wizard? Why do you want to know?

Comment: Because I have no idea if such an id is needed for a custom wizard and I'm curious.